# Disconnect signed on user iSeries Navigator

Tags: ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am using iSeries Navigator 7.1
Is there an option to disconnect the current signed on user?
I think in version 4, there was an option.

The hierarchy is as following:

- MyConnections

  - Databases

    - Schema

      - Library A
      - Library B
      - Library C
        As per my understanding, on each library, I can have a different signed on user. Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Disconnect? From which server? Connections may be established to any or all of the host servers, and potentially many connections might exist to any one of them (possibly under different user IDs). Is "current signed on user" intended to be the same as a default user configured in iNav?

Comment: I updated my post, thanks

Comment: Again, Is "current signed on user" intended to be the same as a default user configured in iNav? Things can work differently when iNav has a default user configured. Is one configured, or is user ID always prompted?

Comment: "current signed on user" intended to be the same as a default user configured in iNav: yes exactly
User ID not prompted

Comment: I'm not aware of anything useful that can be done when a default User ID is configured. When configured, the question effectively becomes "How can I change the internal working of iNav without having the source code?" You can change users, e.g., 'prompting' or potentially CWBLOGON.EXE and other methods, but I don't know how anything like your question can be done **unless you create your own function** outside of iNav.

Answer (score -1):

I would have preferred to leave a comment....and maybe I missed something in the question, BUT.... 
Is there an option to disconnect the current signed on user? 
If you log into iNav, the hierarchy is something like :

my connections

the 400's IP address (or server address if you prefer)

work management

Systems

subsystems

Active Subsystems

Qinter (Q interactive)

bounce a user from there. 
Green screen WRKACTJOB  is easier for me. I just scroll to QINTER and "4" the user, especially when they lock files that are needed for back up process. Seems evil but sometimes required.

Comment: I would have shot a screen print, but eh.  I broke it down like the "questioner"  hierarchy.  I guess the -1 was for timeliness.  =)